# iOS app signing

Tags: ios

Okay, here's the question.

I have an iPhone app, which is already signed. Can I install it on any iOS device I want to, even if it's UDID is not linked to my developer account? I.e. can I just drag my app's .ipa to iTunes and sync it with other device?

Answer (score 0):

no you cannot. if you want to do that, you have to make sure the devices signature is registered beforehand

if its signed, why not stick it on the store and get it from there?

Comment: It's an app for internal use, there's no need to submit it on the store.

Comment: in that case refer to this article (: http://mobiledan.net/2012/03/02/5-options-for-distributing-ios-apps-to-a-limited-audience-legally/

Comment: Thank you. Seems that we'll have to use enterprise program :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're only intending to go the official way, then not. Apple says: "Hey developer, let you pay to us in order to run your **own code** on your **own device."**

If you have the possibility to jailbreak your phone, then it's possible.